# Lightbox and Wordpress 404 error

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I'm having issues with using lightbox with a layerslider plugin. I managed to install lightbox by calling the scripts in my function.php folder and have added a rel attribute so I can use lightbox with my gallery. When I apply the attribute lightbox does function but it brings up a 404 Background error as you can see here

http://sportsentertainmentattorney.com/sports-law/

I followed this link to install lightbox - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-a-responsive-lightbox-to-your-wordpress-theme--wp-28100

When you click the bottom second to the left picture, the lightbox function does appear but the 404 error shows up. I can't seem to locate the problem, can anyone help me out?

Comment: You have 3 different lightbox script loaded on your page! Prettyphoto, Lightbox and Fancybox. Start by choosing just one to use.

Comment: hi, thank you for the help I didn't realize. I managed to get fancybox working but I just have one more issue now. When you click the picture and the fancybox pops up, the image from the layer slider dissapears behind it as you can see frmo the bottom second left picture. Any ideas?